Exercising Company Options - How quickly does the company need to provide the shares? According to legislation and/or case law?(UK)
I have been issued company options. I notified the company that I want to exercise them, but they said they need to setup a system for that to happen. That was about a month ago.
I am now leaving the company but I want to exercise the options before I leave (because they will expire once I leave).
My understanding is that, in the UK there is nothing in law saying how quickly they need to give you the shares and certificates.
I am not asking for specific legal advice for my situation
What legislation or case law, would be used to determine the maximum length of time a company should issue shares?

Do you have a contract or something setting out your rights to get shares? It may well set out a timescale.

Yes, and it doesn't set out a timescale.
